# How can I delay the bluetooth permission bluetooth on android app?

Tags: android

Im creating an android app, and it beggins with a zoom out transition. And it has a popup that ask the user to allow or not the use of bluetooth. The thing is i want to have a delay on that popup so the user can see the transition.

Comment: may be AnimationListener can do the trick, question is not very clear. Are you explicitly asking for bluetooth permission (as in for 23 and above), is it after Activity transition or after some view transition?

Comment: The bluetoth permission is on the androidManifest.xml and as soon as i open the app it asks the user if the app is allowed to use the bluetooth, so  the popup with th permission opens while the zoom out transition is occurring and i would like that the popup would wait untill the end of the tansition to show

Comment: It will be easier if you can post some code, just an assumption if you can wait for activity to load fully and then make any call related to bluetooth api it can work.